# Female voice output in voce speech synthesizer

Tags: java, text-to-speech, freetts

I am using voce speech synthesizer for my text to speech application in Java.

http://voce.sourceforge.net/

It has default male voice. How can I get a female voice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is outlined in the project's [White Paper](http://voce.sourceforge.net/files/VoceWhitePaper.pdf)

> Adding new synthesized voices. These can be imported into FreeTTS (and thus Voce) from voice creation software projects like Festvox and MBROLA.